TeXshop stopped typesetting
TeXshop stopped compiling  when I click on the "Typeset" (the panel is not highlighetd)
When I open a file in Texshop, the top panel containing the various option  - Typeset, Program,  etc is turned light grey and does not highlight.
If I click on Program and select xelatex,  the "Typeset" is not highlighted, and nothing happens if I click the "Typeset" option to compile.
Do I have to uninstall TeXshop alone and re-install? If so, how to go about it ?
The TeXLive is fine and I can compile on the Terminal using commands

Maybe starting TeXshop from the terminal will let you see error messages in the terminal.

@nplatis Do you actually use a Mac? This advice really makes no sense.

Try simply reinstalling TeXShop from here. It is unrelated to TeX Live, but making sure you have an up to date version of TeXShop is likely to solve the problem since your MacTeX is working.

Okay.  To install a most recent version of Texshopqs suggested by you, should I first delete the old version that I am having problem with?

It should overwrite the existing one, but there's no harm in deleting it either.
